# Comparing and Concatenating Tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples, concatenation

I have a python tuple whose elements are actually sentences. I want to compare the first letters of each element and if they are lowercase, I join it to the previous element. And if they aren't I just join the first element.
For instance if I have:

```
tuple1 = ('Traditionally, companies have been communicating', 'with consumers through traditional or old media.', 'The rapid changes in the cyber world.', 'This is another sentence', 'which is incomplete.')
```

My result should be:

```
tuple1 = ('Traditionally, companies have been communicating with consumers through traditional or old media.', 'The rapid changes in the cyber world.', 'This is another sentence which is incomplete.')
```

This is my working code:

```
i=0 
while i<(len(tuple1)-1):
   if tuple1[i+1][0].islower():
       tuple1[i] + " " + tuple[i+1]
   i+=1
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You are on the right track, with one problem: you cannot modify the contents of your tuple. Tuples are immutable. You have to create a new tuple to hold the results. In fact, I'd create a new `list` instead, because then it will be easier to fill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools  
tuple1 = ('Traditionally, companies have been communicating', 'with consumers through traditional or old media.', 'The rapid changes in the cyber world.', 'This is another sentence', 'which is incomplete.')
new_data = tuple(' '.join(i[-1] for i in b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(tuple1), key=lambda x:x[-1][0].islower() or tuple1[x[0]+1][0].islower() if x[0]+1 < len(tuple1) else True))
```

Output:

```
('Traditionally, companies have been communicating with consumers through traditional or old media.', 'The rapid changes in the cyber world.', 'This is another sentence which is incomplete.')
```

Comment: Oooo, I didn't know about the groupby method in itertools! Very nice.

Comment: This actually works for the initial problem. But it doesn't work if there are multiple sentences. I've edited the tuple to add more sentences. Can you edit the code accordingly? Thanks

Comment: @Ajax1234 I'm trying to use the same procedure to join sentences which do not end with `'.'`, `'?'`, or `'!'`. I tried restructuring the code you gave to `tuple(' '.join(i[-1] for i in b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(tuple1), key=lambda x:x[-1][-1] != '.' or tuple1[x[0]+1][-1] == '.' if x[0]+1 < len(tuple1) else True))`. Such that if you have `tuple1 = ('Traditionally', 'consumers.', 'The rapid changes?', 'This sentence', 'which is incomplete.')` `new_data` should give `'Traditionally consumers.', 'The rapid changes?', 'This sentence which is incomplete.'` Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @TheSolider I tested you new input on the current code and got your desired output, `('Traditionally consumers.', 'The rapid changes?', 'This sentence which is incomplete.')`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Ajax1234 It works but not perfectly. If the input changes to say `tuple1 = ('Traditionally', 'consumers.', 'The rapid changes', 'This sentence', 'which is incomplete.')`, I don't get the desired output (which are complete sentences terminating with a full-stop, question mark, or exclamation mark). And how do I account for `'?'` and `'!'`

Comment: @TheSolider So you wish to match until a `[?!.]`? What would be your desired output from the example in your last comment?

Comment: @Ajax1234 `'Traditionally consumers.', 'The rapid changes This sentence which is incomplete.'` And also if those fullstops were `'?'` or `'!'`

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks for your efforts and patience, but if you change the input to `'Traditionally', 'consumers.', 'The rapid changes.', 'This sentence', 'which is incomplete.'`, it should give `'Traditionally consumers.', 'The rapid changes.', 'This sentence which is incomplete.'` However, it gives, `'Traditionally consumers. The rapid changes.', 'This sentence which is incomplete.'`

Answer (score 3):

Hope this does what you are looking for. I did it without using any external modules.

```
b = ('Traditionally, companies have been communicating', 'with consumers through traditional or old media.', 'The rapid changes in the cyber world.')
i=0
a=[]
num=0
for element in b:
    print(element)
    if element[i][0].islower():
        a[-1]=a[-1]+element
    else:
        a.append(element)
        num=num+1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

As the first comment stated, tuples are immutable. Using lists might be easier and if you really need a tuple you can convert your result list to one afterward.

```
phrases = ['Traditionally, companies have been communicating', 'with consumers through traditional or old media.', 'The rapid changes in the cyber world.', 'This is another sentence', 'which is incomplete.']
def join_on_uppercase(items):
  final_phrases = []
  temp_list = [phrases[0]]
  for phrase in phrases[1:]:
    if phrase[0].isupper():
      final_phrases.append(' '.join(temp_list))
      temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(phrase)
  final_phrases.append(' '.join(temp_list))
  return tuple(final_phrases)
print(join_on_uppercase(phrases))
```

That should take care of it. You need the final line to clear out the temp_list.